# Python Tkinter Text Area set cursor to end

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Tkinter `Text()` object and I append lines to it using `.insert(END, string)`. When the text fills the available area, I'd expect it to scroll down to show the bottom line of text in the view, but it doesn't scroll (meaning the user has to scroll themselves to see the latest text). I've had a look at the `mark_set()` method but I can't seem to figure out how to get the cursor to the index of the last item of text.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Does `mark_set(CURSOR, END)` work? I think there might be a `see()` method to scroll.

Comment: Setting a mark is completely different from scrolling to the bottom of a document. Are you just wanting to move the cursor to the end, or scroll to the bottom? (or both?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As usual with Tkinter, there are a number of ways to do this, but one is the easiest: [`Text.see`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.see-method):

```
text.insert(END, "spam\n")
text.see(END)
```

If you want to make sure the *start* of the new text is visible, not the end of it, or if you only want to do this if the end was already visible beforehand or if the text is active, etc., you may need to look at the other options: `scan_mark`/`scan_dragto`, or `yview` and friends.

Comment: Tried this just now and it doesn't seem to have any affect - I'm inserting in the same was as your post suggests, but the `.see(END)` method doesn't change the viewpoint

Comment: @AlexBlundell: Can you show your code? Also, what platform are you on? I tried it with a plain Text and with one hooked up to a Scrollbar, on OS X 10.8 and an old Fedora box, and they both scrolled the viewport, but that doesn't guarantee that it'll work with all code and on all platforms, the way Tk is…

Comment: @AlexBlundell: this definitely is the solution. If calling `see` doesn't work for you, you're doing something wrong. Please show us a small program that illustrates your problem so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: I was calling the function from the wrong place - this does indeed work :)

Comment: This is wrong. The only method I got to work was `text.mark_set(tk.INSERT, tk.END)`